# Can't find ram on ASUS & what is Max RAM?

Tags: memory, asus-laptop

I am looking to upgrade the ram in my Asus X54C laptop. Currently, it is running on 2GB (according to Control Panel > System).

Mr.Memory @ [this link](http://www.mrmemory.co.uk/memory-ram-upgrades/asus/laptop/x54c) says 4GB is the maximum. They also say:

> This machine only has one memory slot, to upgrade you will need to
>   remove the original memory and install the new memory in its place.

I opened the case just to be sure, but the memory slot is empty!!  No sign of memory anywhere!

I guess it is the case that the 2GB of memory is hidden somewhere else on the device.  The [manufacturer says](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X54C/specifications/):

> DDR3 1333 MHz SDRAM, 2 GB, OnBoard Memory, 1 x SO-DIMM socket for
>   expansion up to 6 GB SDRAM

If I was to buy more memory to max it out, I should get 4GB, not 2GB, right?

Comment: I read this as you can put a 6GB RAM into the empty slot but if you are worry, you can get a 4GB RAM.

Comment: ASUS says its 6GB so its 6GB provided you are looking up the correct model on ASUS's website.  I am going to guess this is a product with a soldered 2GB module and a user replaceable module that supports up to 4GB ( hence the 6GB limit ) **easily enough to confirm by reading the manual** I suggest you do that

Answer (score 2):

I have an ASUS A54C laptop.  ASUS says it has an 8GB max. There is 2GB hardwired on the laptop and mine had a 4GB SODIMM installed.

I installed an 8GB SODIMM and it now has 10GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I have an A54C and can completely sympathise with your problem. Your Asus "User Manual" won't help, and ASUS doesn't release a motherboard manual for laptops the way they do with desktop motherboards.

I suggest running [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), and you will probably find 2GB native on the motherboard, + 2, or 4GB for the expansion slot.

You will also probably find that just running CPU-Z on the native RAM (with the expansion slot empty) returns an answer of PC10600 (666MHz frequency / 1333.33 MT/s).

*Note: There is no such thing as a 6GB expansion module, so it's either 2, or 4.*